# How to send a PHP variable via post in HTML form

Tags: php, html

I have this line of code

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='var' value="echo "$delim"; ">";
```

and get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

I cant seem to figure out the right way to write this. Im writting html in php, and im writing php within that html, as you can see.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had an issue in escaping the quotes. You could do like below representation.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='var' value=".$delim." >"; //preferred solution
```

You can even give a shot on this.

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='var' value=$delim >"; // Variables under double quotes will be parsed.
```

**`Sidenote : Always make use of a good PHP IDE to find such errors on the fly.`**

Comment: It's likely that the `$delim` by it's name in this question might not contain spaces(or other characters e.g. `=`), if it does then attribute values should be wrapped with quotes.

Comment: @vee, I didn't cuz that would be synonymous to your answer so I gave an alternate way :)

Answer (score 1):

Shankar Damodaran has an adequate solution but there are multiple syntaxes you can use to accomplish the same thing:

```
<?php
echo "<input type='hidden' name='var' value='$delim'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='var' value='" . $delim . "'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='var' value='{$delim}'>";
?>
<input type='hidden' name='var' value='<?php echo $delim; ?>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest `echo` inside `echo`.  Try:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='var' value='$delim'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='var' value='".$delim."' />";
```

or may be you try this coding style:
make html and php different, so it's little easier for you.

```
<?php //your code ?>
<input type='text' name='var' value='<?php echo $delim;?>' />
<?php //your code ?>
```